# What is the input for Conv2d for text?

Tags: python, cnn, pytorch

I have an embedding layer that returns a tensor of type: batch x max_len x embeddings_dim (8 x 200 x 300)

I want to input this to a Conv2d layer with kernel 3x3.

I tried

```
conv =  Conv2d(300, 100, (3,3))
conv(embedding) # embedding.shape = (8 x 200 x 300 x 1)
```

I get an error:

```
Torch: invalid memory size -- maybe an overflow?
```

What should be the input of the Conv2d ?

Comment: You can use Conv1d layers as well on sequences of integer tokens.